# How to correct this in Scala?: method apply in object Timeout is deprecated: please be explicit about the time

Tags: scala

This code:

```
val t = Timeout(15000).duration
print(t)
```

results in this Scala compilation warning:

method apply in object Timeout is deprecated: please be explicit about the time unit and use the two-argument version
[warn]     val t = Timeout(15000).duration

What is the correct way to specify the two-argument version?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume you are talking about [Akka's Timeout](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.2/#akka.util.Timeout$).

Try this

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
Timeout(15000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

You could also use:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt
Timeout.durationToTimeout(15000.millis)
```

Or using the implicit conversion:

```
val myTimeOut: Timeout = 15000.millis
```